# Translation jobs are coming into "Error Sending" state quite often?

Tags: 2013-sp1, worldserver, translation-manager

We have started getting a very strange error since few weeks where users are launching translation jobs with component bundles in it and the job comes in "Error Sending" state with the following error description:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive. 
>      at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)
>
> ---
>
> Source Publication URI: tcm:0-6-1 Source Publication title: 020 
>   Content (-)(EN-US)
>
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)

The strange thing is that sometimes the bundle with 200 components is getting delivered to Translation agency successfully but the bundle with 60 components gets stuck in this state and the bundle which gets stuck not necessarily stuck completely, meaning TMS is able to send the partial components (1 Job say of 50 components) to World Server.
For example, out of 60 components, 50 are reaching successfully but because the job is in Error State, even if Translation Agency finishes the translation at their end there is no way we can get the Translated Components back in Tridion.

Any help would greatly appreciate.

We have SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and World Server as Translation server

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates a network issue - I suspect this more so as you state

> *sometimes* the bundle with 200 components is getting delivered

Can you check the event system logs?

Have you set the Translation Logs to debug also? - Perhaps there's something in here given the service polls the World Server service - is it often reporting issues in the background too?

With regards part of the jobs being received - but then not being able to retrieve them this does sound very strange indeed and something I would take-up with World Server support (irrespective of where the network issue lies); I would expect that World Server would 'know' the expected size of the package and not process it if not complete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have raised the issue with SDL support & World Server, they are now analyzing the issue. And yes they too suspect that it's a network issue.

Comment: No worries Yash. Please do update this thread with the additional tests/log reviews that take please to deduce/confirm the root cause.